# Access variable from a different function from another file

Tags: python, function, nested-function

I have a file **`myfunctions.py`** in directory mypythonlib

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests

def champs_info(champname:str, tier_str:int):  
    url = f"https://auntm.ai/champions/{champname}/tier/{tier_str}"
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)

    information = r.html.find("div.sc-hiSbYr.XqbgT")
    sig = r.html.find('div.sc-fbNXWD.iFMyOV')
    tier_access = information[0]
    tier = tier_access.text
```

I want to access the variable **`tier`** through another file- **`test_myfunctions.py`**
but the thing is I also have to give parameters to the function `champs_info` so that it could access the url accordingly.

```
from mypythonlib import myfunctions
def test_champs_info():
    return myfunctions.champs_info("abomination",6).tier
```

But while running this code, I am getting the error-

```
./tests/test_myfunctions.py::test_champs_info Failed: [undefined]AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tier'
def test_champs_info():
>       return myfunctions.champs_info("abomination",6).tier
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tier'

tests/test_myfunctions.py:3: AttributeError
```

Any Solution for this and why is this code not able to access the variable?
I wrote `myfunctions.champs_info("abomination",6).tier` in hope for that it's gonna take the `tier` variable from the `champs_info` function while giving it the parameters required all from the myfunctions file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the value of a variable in a function by 1) returning the value in the function, 2) use a global variable in the module, or 3) define a class.

If only want to access a single variable local to a function then the function should return that value. A benefit of the class definition is that you may define as many variables as you need to access.

**1. Return value**

```python
def champs_info(champname:str, tier_str:int):  
    ...
    tier = tier_access.text
    return tier
```

**2. global**

```python
tier = None
def champs_info(champname:str, tier_str:int):
    global tier
    ...
    tier = tier_access.text
```

Global tier vairable is accessed.

```
from mypythonlib import myfunctions

def test_champs_info():
    myfunctions.champs_info("abomination", 6)
    return myfunctions.tier

print(test_champs_info())
```

**3. class definition:**

```python
class Champ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tier = None
    def champs_info(self, champname:str, tier_str:int):  
        ...
        self.tier = tier_access.text
```

test_functions.py can call champs_info() in this manner.

```
from mypythonlib import myfunctions

def test_champs_info():
    info = myfunctions.Champ()
    info.champs_info("abomination", 6)
    return info.tier
    
print(test_champs_info())
```

Comment: Using the class method, Can I use a way In which I create a nested function inside `champs_info` and access it outside the file?

Comment: @Dheeraj-Tech - updated with how you would call champs_info() in another script/class and access tier variable.

Comment: Cool!! This actually worked! Thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

In myfunctions.champs_info() add a **return tier**

and in the script test_myfunctions.py remove **.tier**

Comment: But what If I wanted to access more than 1 variable from champs_info()?

Comment: I tried to create a inner function inside  `champs_info()` so that I could call any function if I wanted a variable to return, but I was not able to access that also :(

Comment: **Python variables defined in functions are not accessible outside of functions unless they are attached to an object accessible outside of the function.** you will have to change variables as such **champs_info.tier =  'xyz'** ,and access them the same way outside the function.

Comment: Or as mentioned use global variables. but then make sure whenever using global variables that data is not getting **mixed up somewhere later on in the script!**

Answer (score 0):

You just have to return tier from **champs_info()** function

Just like this:

**myfunctions.py**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests

def champs_info(champname:str, tier_str:int):  
    url = f"https://auntm.ai/champions/{champname}/tier/{tier_str}"
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1)

    information = r.html.find("div.sc-hiSbYr.XqbgT")
    sig = r.html.find('div.sc-fbNXWD.iFMyOV')
    tier_access = information[0]
    tier = tier_access.text
    return tier               # <---- Focus Here
```

**test_myfunctions.py**

```
import myfunctions

print(temp.champs_info("americachavez", 6))
```

Just it. You're done.